# how to add 1 .txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt at the end of each line of file

Tags: shell, sed, sh, busybox

a.txt

```
12
23
45
56
```

Expected output:

```
12 >1.txt
23 >2.txt
45 >3.txt
56 >4.txt
```

I have tried below-given this command but it's not working:

```
sed -i s/$/\>1.txt/ a.txt
```

I want to store the value `12` in the file `1.txt`; `23` in `2.txt`; `45` in `3.txt`; and `56` in `4.txt`

I am using Busybox, so I don't have Bash, and non-portable uses of Awk etc will also probably not work.

Comment: Your comments reveal that you are on Busybox so I added a passage about this and removed the [tag:bash] tag. You really should state your requirements in the question rather than separately gripe under each answer that the code they posted fails to fulfill requirements which you failed to mention up front.

Comment: If you have a custom build of Busybox which excludes some of the standard utilities, you would have to mention that, too. I distinctly remember using Awk on Busybox in, like, 1992.

Comment: https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/busybox.1.html has some additional guidance. Running `busybox` without arguments should reveal which applets it was compiled to include. If you don't have the `awk` applet, maybe edit your question to reveal which utilities exactly are available. `sed` is an extremely poor fit for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk and increment an int for each line

```
awk 'BEGIN{i=1} /.*/{printf "%s >%d.txt\n",$0,i; i++}' a.txt
```

Comment: busybox not supports the awk command.

Comment: BusyBox v1.01 (2021.12.29-16:10+0000) multi-call binary

Comment: That's not true; standard Busybox should include Awk. 1.01 sounds like a really old version, though; the date should correspond to something like 1.32

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & expr):

```
sed -n 'x;s/.*/expr & + 1/e;x;/\S/G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/echo "\1" >\2.txt/e' file
```

Store a counter in the hold space and increment it for each line input.

Append the counter to the current line and then format an expression to store the current line in a file designated by the counter and evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

If your *actual* question is how to write each line to a new file, try

```
awk 'NR>1 { close(f) }
    { f=++n ".txt"; print >f }' a.txt
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/a65wFT
(IdeOne runs on Linux but I have separately tested this on BusyBox v1.34.1 (2021-12-29 21:12:15 UTC))

If you can't get Awk to work, try

```
n=0
while read -r line; do
    echo "$line" >"$((++n)).txt"
done <a.txt
```

Perhaps see also [`split`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/split.1.html); however, the Busybox `split` appears to have limited support for controlling the generated output file names.

Comment: awk not supported by busybox

Comment: Sure it is, I just booted up a Busybox Docker container and it's there just like the other expected POSIX tools.

Comment: BusyBox v1.01 (2021.12.29-16:10+0000) Built-in shell (ash)

Comment: Added a simple shell script too now, but I'm pretty sure Busybox included Awk already in the 1990s (and correspondingly, if you have a really old and crufty version, I'm not sure it will understand `$((++n))`)